# Logging using Serilog to SQLite sink

Tags: c#, sqlite, logging, .net-5, serilog

I'm not able to make SeriLog work with SQLite sink.

[Source code](https://github.com/affableashish/tips-and-tricks/tree/feature/serilog-to-sqlite). Project setup:

| Packages installed: | SQLite database: |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

appsettings.json :

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Error",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "SQLite",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=WebApp.db",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "batchSize": 1,
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {MachineName} {EnvironmentUserName} [{Level:u4}] <{ThreadId}> [{SourceContext:l}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        },
        "theme": "AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate"
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "WithEnvironmentUserName" ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebAppConnection": "Data Source=WebApp.db"
  }
}
```

`AppDbContext` file (shows Log table):

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}
```

`Log` model :

```
public class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(500)")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(500)")]
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(500)")]
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(800)")]
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(500)")]
    public string Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // I added this portion - start.
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "EMPTYENVIRONMENTNAME";
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        ConfigureLogger(config);

        // I added this portion - end.

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); // I wrapped this inside try catch.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Serilog.Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Serilog.Log.Information("Web host stopped.");
            Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush(); // <-- I added this.
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog() // <-- I added this.
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

     // I added this.
    public static void ConfigureLogger(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                                .CreateLogger();

        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
    }
```

Startup.cs :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // I added this portion - start.
        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebAppConnection"));
        });

        services.AddScoped<IAppRepository, AppRepository>();

        // I added this portion - end.
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

This SQLite sink doesn't log anything. It doesn't even throw any errors. I only see the logs in console but not in database.

```
_logger.LogInformation("Test message.");
```

Comment: You aren't getting any errors, so how do you know it's not working and you just don't realize it? Did you try providing a full path for your DB file instead of just a filename?

Comment: @mason I queried the Db and there aren't any new records inserted. How do I provide a full path name? Like `Data Source=.\WebApp.db`? Is that correct? My Db is in the project folder.

Comment: You queried a DB. How do you know it was the correct one? And no, a full path would start with a drive letter. If you start with a dot, that is a relative path.

Comment: @mason : I queried the Db by creating a method that returned `context.Logs.ToList();`. And that returned my 'Seed' log record. No new records were there. And I'm not sure why you'd recommend putting full path for the Db? Isn't relative path a better choice if I want to deploy the app to some other environment where I might not have directory path matching the path I have in my local development machine? And since my database is right there in the project folder, do I even need to specify a path for the Db?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the problem that you might be logging to a different file than you think you're logging to. That's one behavior that could have described the behavior you're seeing. Ultimately you need to do what makes sense for your app, but when things aren't working properly, you need to start verifying everything in order to narrow down the problem, rather than just assuming that everything is what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. SQLite sink is a bit different than MSSqlServer sink. You'll need to add `public string RenderedMessage { get; set; }` into your Log Entity class to process the SQLite message.

Also this `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));` should tell you the db connection error.

Below is how I would structure your `sqliteDbPath:`

```
var sqlPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/WebApp.db";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.SQLite(sqliteDbPath:sqlPath,tableName:"Log",batchSize:1)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong? I still can't make it work. I'm using `appsettings.json` to get my Serilog settings. It logs to Console correctly but not to SQLite. In my code, when users get to Home page, a log should be created (it doesn't). You can also view the logs from the Home page. My code is here: https://github.com/affableashish/tips-and-tricks/tree/feature/serilog-to-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

To be able to configure a new Sink to the configuration you need to define the "Using" section.

eg.

```
    "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Information"
        },
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.SQLite" ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
              "configure": [
                {
                  "Name": "Console"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "SQLite",
            "Args": {
              "sqliteDbPath": "pathToDatabase"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Alos, you don't need to create a table on your own. it will be done by the library

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem today. When I tried to log a few test logs into two sinks (File and SQLite) - logs were inserted only to the file. SQLite db was created, but log table was empty. My logger configuration looked like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("logs.txt")
    .WriteTo.SQLite("logs.db")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Solution: I set `batchSize` parameter value in `WriteTo.SQLite()` method to `1` while I was testing. Then, logs were inserted into both sinks, just as expected. In first scenario table was empty, because default value of `batchSize` is 100. Logger configuration after change (just for a test scenario):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("logs.txt")
    .WriteTo.SQLite(sqliteDbPath: "logs.db", batchSize: 1)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Another option: invoke `Log.CloseAndFlush()` before closing application.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong? I still can't make it work. I'm using `appsettings.json` to get my Serilog settings. It logs to Console correctly but not to SQLite. In my code, when users get to Home page, a log should be created (it doesn't). You can also view the logs from the Home page. I have updated my question that has a link to my code repository.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar issue in my code.

Specifying the "WriteTo" in appsettings.json like below, did the trick for me.

```
"WriteTo": [
{
    "Name": "SQLite",
    "Args": {
        "sqliteDbPath": "C:\\MyFolder\\My.db",
        "tableName": "Logs"
    }
}
```

You can also specify a relative path

```
"WriteTo": [
{
    "Name": "SQLite",
    "Args": {
        "sqliteDbPath": "Logs/My.db",
        "tableName": "Logs"
    }
}
```

But note that you will then find your database **relative to the bin folder** of your application.
Mine was in *MyWebProject/bin/Debug/net7.0/Logs/My.db*

I hope this helps.